# how to run an awk in a loop with variable

Tags: loops, unix, awk

I want to do this but it doesn't work

`input.csv` is like this :

```
name  number
toto  125
tata  126
popo  126
nono  127
```

`file.csv` is like this

```
number

126
127
```

desired `output.csv` is like this :

```
name  number
tata  126
popo  126
nono  127

for number in $(cat ~/Documents/file.csv) ;
do
    awk -F, '$2 == "$number|cut -d',' -f1"' input.csv >> output.csv
done
```

Comment: Thanks for showing your efforts which you have put in order to solve your own problem. Please do add samples of input and expected output too in your question for better understanding of your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use shell variables in an awk script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script)

Comment: Sorry it doesn't answer my question

Comment: You're trying to use shell syntax and call a Unix tool from inside an awk script. awk is not shell. awk and shell are 2 completely different tools, each with their own language, syntax, semantics, scope, etc. You can no more use shell syntax and directly call Unix tools from inside an awk script that you can from inside a C program.

Comment: Once you update your question to show why you think you need a shell loop calling awk then we can help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use a shell loop. It can be done easily in a single awk like this:

```sh
awk 'FNR == NR {seen[$1]; next} $2 in seen' file.csv input.csv > output.csv
```

```sh
cat output.csv

name  number
tata  126
popo  126
nono  127
```

Comment: thank you but I need a loop because the file.csv has 25 000 numbers

Comment: and I must use a loop because I process this file before (this part is not in my example)

Comment: Then please update your question and provide full picture. Awk can process millions of records easily

Comment: I tried csvgrep -c 2 -m ' "$variable" ' ~/Desktop/Test.csv , it does not work

Comment: I didn't suggest `csvgrep` in my answer.